# Python: pass log file directory as an argument

Tags: python, logging

In my Python script, I have a logger defined as follows:

```
RUN_LOG_BASE_DIR='/tmp/'
RUN_LOG_FILE_NAME = 'process_cc_log.txt'

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

runlog_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)s line-%(lineno)d\t\t%(levelname)s\t%(message)s')
runlog_handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(os.path.join(RUN_LOG_BASE_DIR, 
                RUN_LOG_FILE_NAME), when='midnight', backupCount=30)
runlog_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
runlog_handler.setFormatter(runlog_formatter)
logger.addhandler(runlog_handler)
```

I tried passing in the RUN_LOG_BASE_DIR as an argument(/logs) to the main function, but it still writes to the /tmp directory.

main:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    RUN_LOG_BASE_DIR = sys.argv[1]
```

How do I pass the base directory as an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because the code where you set up the logger runs before the `if __name__ == '__main__`.

For example

```py
MY_STRING = "hello"
print(MY_STRING)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   MY_STRING = "goodbye"
```

The above code will always print `hello`, because the print statement is run before the `if` check.

However, if this was written as

```
def print_string(s):
   print(s)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   print("goodbye")
```

Then the program would accurately print out "goodbye".

A similar concept can be applied to your problem. Move your logging setup code inside a function, and then call the function with your desired logging dir.